Car AC does work well intermittently
My Car AC is good when driving but when idling at sometime and have too much heat outside, the cooling decreased gradually. I have already replaced auxillary fan and also added an extra fan on the condenser. I got a good reading sometimes at 30psi low side and 180 - 200 high side but when the coldness start decreasing the reading becam 50psi on low side and 200 at high side. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model of the vehicle in question?

Hi. Suzuki Celerio 2018. I'm not sure if its the same model on the other country.

Is the cooling fan running when low side/50 psi, high side/200 psi and low cooling occurs? Did you top off or refill using sealer?

Yes. 2 Cooling fans are running normally. I didt not top off yet as it is working well intermittently.
